# How to wrap grid/flex items to fill rows as fully as possible

Tags: css

I need to display a grid of items in a container with variable width. All items are either have a column span width of 1 or 2. Is it possible in pure CSS to dynamically order the items so that 1-column width items move to fill gaps in rows above when there isn't enough room for a 2-column width item that would otherwise precede it?

The closest working example I have is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/amdilley/zt4v3pqd/).

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.box>div {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

div.long {
  grid-column-start: auto;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="long"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The problem is the gap seen in the 3-col wide state. The long item doesn't have room to wrap so a gap is preserved instead. Is it possible to promote eligible items to fill the gap?

2-col wide:
[image]

3-col wide:
[image]

4-col wide:
[image]

Comment: grid-auto-flow:dense

Answer (score 0):

Per Temani's comment the answer is to add `grid-auto-flow: dense;` to container element.